# Get Back ups of mySql database periodically

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

I have a mySql database which i need to get backup of data after every 24 hours. 
I don't have any idea about how to getting backups. 
How may i do this?
please help..

Comment: Write a cron job that uses `mysqldump`.

Comment: @Barmar This should be an answer and not a comment :P

Comment: @DamianNikodem It's not detailed enough to be an answer. It's not really even an appropriate question.

Comment: Both true I guess., I suppose this would be better suited to server fault.

Comment: @Barmar  What is a corn job ... is there any place to read about corn jobs?

Comment: A `cron` job is a way of running a command periodically on Unix. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cron%20job%20wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Setup a server cron which runs mysqldump command after some interval (e.g. 24 hours)

```
mysqldump -hMY_HOST.COM -uDB_USERNAME -pDB_PASSWORD USERNAME_DATABASENAME > MysqlDump.sql
```

After creating dump file. Setup another cron to copy this dump to target server(preferably local) make this execute with same interval of above cron.

```
scp user@MY_HOST.COM:/some/path/file user2@MY_HOST2.COM:/some/path/file
```

**NOTE: This commands may cause high server load (make sure you are executing them when server having minimum load)**

**Reference :** http://www.bradtrupp.com/mysql-backup-cron.html